# SQL like on concatted field?

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

Is it possible in mysql to make select and search on concatted field?

```
This is example: SELECT concat(members.name, " " ,members.surname) AS i FROM members where i LIKE '%string%'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't alias a column in the select clause and then use it in the where clause.

But there are lots of ways to do what you're trying to do.

The closest solution is to use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`:

```
SELECT concat(members.name, " " ,members.surname) AS i 
FROM members 
HAVING i LIKE '%string%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the concat into the WHERE

```
SELECT concat(members.name, " ", members.surname) as i FROM members WHERE concat(members.name, " ", members.surname) LIKE '%somestring%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, with something like this:

```
select * from
(SELECT concat(members.name, " " ,members.surname) AS i 
FROM members) con
where con.i LIKE '%string%'
```

Saludos ;)